# Examine the almost uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Examine the almost uniform convergence of the function with the formula

$$ f_n: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R \mbox{ such that } f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{e^{(nx-1)^2}} $$.

Can somebody check if my attempt is correct?

### solution

point convergence is easy to show (I don't have problem with that.
Let
   $$ c := \mbox{ argument for which $|f_n|$ reaches maximum value} $$ 
    $c$ exists because in bounded interval monotonous $f_n$ reaches own extremes 
    $$D = [a,b]$$
    $$ \sup_{x \in D} \left|\frac{nx}{e^{(nx-1)^2}} \right| = \left|\frac{nc}{e^{(nc-1)^2}} \right|$$
Of course series with given asymptotic converges
so we have local uniform convergance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monotonicity is not true so your argument does not work. $f_n(x)=g(nx)$ where $g(y)=ye^{-(y-1)^{2}}$. It is easy to show that $g(y) \to 0$ so $f_n\to 0$ uniformly in around any point other than $0$. However the sequence does not converge uniformly in any neighborhood of $0$ since $f_n(x)=g(1) >0$ when $x =\frac 1 n$.

Comment: Why, if we have $x=1/n$ we have function which is constant equal $1$

Comment: Suppose we have uniform convergence to $0$ is a neighborhood of $0$. Then there exits $n_0$ such that $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for $n \geq n_0$ for all $x$ in the neighborhood. Since $x=\frac  1 n$ is in the neighborhood  for $n$ sufficiently large we must have $|f_n(\frac 1 n )| <\epsilon$ which means $|g(1)| <\epsilon$. This is a contradiction since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary.

Comment: I understand your current argument but I don't understand this sentence: 
"Monotonicity is not true so your argument does not work". I don't know where I used monotonicity. Imo I used only continuous.

Comment: The point $c$ at which the maximum is attained can depend on $n$ so there is no way of deciding if the convergence is uniform without knowing the xact value of $c$.

Comment: So I can use $c$- method if and only if maximum doesn't depend on $n$, yes?

Comment: You can try to  use the maximum if the function is simple and you can explicitly find the maximum value. But in situations like the present one it is not advisable to use the maximum.

Comment: ok, thanks sir!